# json-c compilation using svn. Cannot connect to a SVN repository

Tags: c, json, svn

I am new to JSON. I am trying to install jason-c library. I am checking out using svn. I am getting the following error:

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.metaparadigm.com/svn/json-c'
svn: E175002: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found http://svn.metaparadigm.com/svn/json-c
```

Can anyone tell me how to install jason-c. I am using fedora.

Comment: Open this in your browser: http://svn.metaparadigm.com/json-c/

Comment: okay thank you. When i run autogen i am getting automake failed error. Is that anything related with libtool ? I have installed libtool-ltdl-devel package. How i can fix this ?

Comment: How you fix it will depend on the error. I don't know what error you get.

Comment: okay. It is successfully installed now.